# Call matlab mex file in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a Matlab mex file with known interface, this mex file is provided by other guys so I cannot access the code. Is there any efficient way to call the mex function in C++? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`mexCallMatlab`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html)?
You may treat the mex file as a standard matlab function and call it from C++ using `mexCallMatlab`.

Answer (score 0):

1. mexext call ***from Matlab*** tells you the allowed compatible for your system. (32 Bit or 64 Bit)
2. mex compiled executables cannot be called from C++ environment *AFAIK*. They work with Matlab command window/ Matlab Function.

Ex:

> system("mymex")  will give me error as:

```
'mymex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

> system("ttt.mexw32");

```
will popup a window asking me to select a program to open that file with.
```

Also I have my own doubts that the .mexw32/.mexw64 's compiled on one system may work on other as with .exe's (executables). The reasons may be incompatible Matlab Release versions etc. (Don't know much about this, please check about it once)

**You can use their mex executables with Matlab easily though.**

Answer (score 0):

mex files are just dynamic libraries.  You can load them with `LoadLibrary` and invoke their functions with `GetProcAddress`. (or on equivalently on *nix, `dlopen` and `dlsym`).

Setting up the parameters to be compatible with what MatLab passes will be a bit of a pain, but not especially difficult.  It will help if you have experience writing mex functions yourself, so you're familiar with the calling convention.

Comment: Does one need to have Matlab installed to use this feature and call mex from C++?